# React fabric ui , grouplist component. Getting the header to look and act like rows

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

i am implementing groupList in my app(vsts extension).
is there a way to make the group header, a regular row like the vsts list

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem with this component.

Comment: i finished my extension 6 months ago... so dont remember this issue... whats your case?

Comment: When grouping items in Detailslist, the group headers are just plain expand/collapse headers with a name that just reveal or hide its children. What I want is the headers to look like its children, have the same columns, not just a name.
Exactly like this: https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-expand-children

Comment: I remeber what i did.i wrote the logic myself, and used asimple table component.

Comment: I can paste the code here if you want

Comment: Thanks, that would be nice!